# ANTLR4 Grammar picks up 'and' and 'or' in variable names

Tags: antlr4

Please help me with my ANTLR4 Grammar.

Sample "formel":

- (Arbejde.ArbejderIKommuneNr=860) and (Arbejde.ErIArbejde = 'J') &
  (Arbejde.ArbejdsTimerPrUge = 40)
- (Ansogeren.BorIKommunen = 'J') and (BeregnDato(Ansogeren.Fodselsdato;
  '+62Å') < DagsDato)
- (Arb.BorI=860)

My problem is that Arb.BorI=860 is not handled correct. I get this error:

- Error: no viable alternative at input '(Arb.Bor' at linenr/position: 1/6 \r\nException: Der blev udløst en undtagelse af typen 'Antlr4.Runtime.NoViableAltException

Please notis that Arb.BorI contains the word 'or'.
I think my problem is that my 'booleanOps' in the grammar override 'datakildefelt'

So... My problem is how do I get my grammar correct - I am stuck, so any help will be appreciated.

My Grammar:

```
grammar UnikFormel;

formel  :  boolExpression   # BooleanExpr
        |  expression       # Expr
        | '(' formel ')'    # Parentes;

boolExpression : ( '(' expression ')'  ) ( booleanOps '(' expression ')'  )+;

expression :  element compareOps element    # Compare;

element : datakildefelt     # DatakildeId
        | function          # Funktion
        | int               # Integer
        | decimal           # Real
        | string            # Text;

datakildefelt : datakilde '.' felt;
datakilde : identifyer;
felt : identifyer;

function : funktionsnavn ('(' funcParameters? ')')?;
funktionsnavn : identifyer;
funcParameters : funcParameter (';' funcParameter)*;
funcParameter   : element;

identifyer : LETTER+;
int : DIGIT+;
decimal :   DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+ | '.' DIGIT+;
string : QUOTE .*?  QUOTE;

booleanOps   : (AND | OR);
compareOps   : (LT | GT | EQ | GTEQ | LTEQ);

QUOTE : '\'';
OPERATOR: '+';
DIGIT: [0-9];
LETTER: [a-åA-Å];
MUL   : '*';
DIV   : '/';
ADD   : '+';
SUB   : '-';
GT    : '>';
LT    : '<';
EQ    : '=';
GTEQ  : '>=';
LTEQ  : '<=';
AND   : '&' | 'and';
OR    : '?' | 'or';
WS    : ' '+ -> skip;
```

Comment: What if you eliminate the third line in `formel` by changing both occurrences of `expression` to `formel` and then the `+` to a `*` in `boolExpression`? I don't think the `or` in Arb.Borl is an issue because then you have `or` in the working examples as well.

Comment: Thank You for your suggestion. I am sorry, but it did not do the trick.
I tryed to change 'or' to 'oor' and 'and' to 'aand' - both in gramar and in test data: (Arbejde.ArbejderIKommuneNr=860) oor (Arbejde.ErIArbejde = 'J')
AND   : '&' | 'aand';
OR    : '?' |  'oor';

Then it works. But I need 'and' and 'or' :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. There were multiple problems. Reading the ANTLR4 book and using "TestRig -gui" got me on the right track. The working grammar is:

```
grammar UnikFormel;

formel  : '(' formel ')'    # Parentes
        | expression        # Expr
        | boolExpression    # BooleanExpr
        ;

boolExpression : '(' expression ')' ( booleanOps '(' expression ')'  )+
        | '(' formel ')' ( booleanOps '(' formel ')'  )+;

expression :  element compareOps element    # Compare;

datakildefelt : ID '.' ID;

function : ID ('(' funcParameters? ')')?;
funcParameters : funcParameter (';' funcParameter)*;
funcParameter   : element;

element : datakildefelt     # DatakildeId
        | function          # Funktion
        | INT               # Integer
        | DECIMAL           # Real
        | STRING            # Text;

booleanOps   : (AND | OR);
compareOps   : ( GTEQ | LTEQ | LT | GT | EQ |);

AND   : '&' | 'and';
OR    : '?' | 'or';
GTEQ  : '>=';
LTEQ  : '<=';
GT    : '>';
LT    : '<';
EQ    : '=';

ID : LETTER ( LETTER | DIGIT)*;
INT : DIGIT+;
DECIMAL :   DIGIT+ '.' DIGIT+ | '.' DIGIT+;
STRING : QUOTE .*?  QUOTE;
fragment QUOTE : '\'';
fragment DIGIT: [0-9];
fragment LETTER: [a-åA-Å];
WS    : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
```

Answer (score 0):

Rules that come first always have precedence. In your case you need to move `AND` and `OR` before `LETTER`. Also there is the same problem with `GTEQ` and `LTEQ`, maybe somewhere else too.

**EDIT**

Additionally, you should make `identifyer` a *lexer rule*, i.e. start with capital letter (`IDENTIFIER` or `Identifier`). The same goes for `int`, `decimal` and `string`. Input is initially a stream of characters and is first processed into a stream of tokens, using only lexer rules. At this point parser rules (those starting with lowercase letter) do not come to play yet. So, to make "BorI" parse as single entity (token), you need to create a lexer rule that matches identifiers. Currently it would be parsed as 3 tokens: `LETTER` (B) `OR` (or) `LETTER` (I).

Comment: Thank You for Your suggestion. I tried:
`AND   : '&' | 'and';
OR    : '?' |  'or';
GTEQ  : '>=';
LTEQ  : '<=';
GT    : '>';
LT    : '<';
EQ    : '=';
QUOTE : '\'';
OPERATOR: '+';
DIGIT: [0-9];
LETTER: [a-åA-Å];
WS   : ' '+ -> skip;`
But it did not change the result.

Comment: Maybe I could help more if the exception text wasn't in language I don't understand.

Comment: Thank You for Your efor. I have tryed to translate the error: Error: no viable alternative at input '(Arb.Bor' at linenumber/position: 1/6 
Exception: Ab exception of type 'Antlr4.Runtime.NoViableAltException' was thrown.

P.s. I am running in Antlr4.Runtime.net45.

Comment: I am working on migrating and old Delphi based system to .net - In the old system, the users can enter business roules 'formel' that evaluate true or false. It is this evaluator I am trying to implement with ANTLR (I already got the visitor running, but I need the 'datakildefelt' - I get it form the parser - since I need to supply the actual values to the visitor when needed (most of the 'datakildefelt' refers to fields of database tables). I hope I got the translation correct, and that You have a better understanding of what I am doing.